# What is causing the thin spacing between the grid border and the grid content and how can I seal it?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I can't seem to make my CSS grid have a flush border around all of my grid elements. There's very thin white line that separates the black grid border from the top and left edges of the grid content. It only seems to happen on some of the edges too which is quite annoying, notice how it is not an issue with the bottom edge.

What can I do to force this to be airtight? With such a simple example still producing this issue I have suspected that it's potentially caused by a screen resolution discrepancy so for reference I am on a Microsoft Surface Laptop 3 and running code in Chrome.

[image: Top and left black border doesn't quite touch the red boxes.]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box1" class="grid-item">Box 1</div>
  <div id="box1" class="grid-item">Box 2</div>
  <div id="box1" class="grid-item">Box 3</div>
  <div id="box1" class="grid-item">Box 4</div>
</div>
```

(Padding and margin set to 0 for everything just to be explicit)

Comment: Are you zoomed in (or out)?

Comment: @j08691 I believe the screenshot is zoomed in. However, I just checked and the problem persists regardless of zoom settings. The spacing grows and shrinks when I zoom like everything else on the page but it doesn't go away.

Comment: This looks like an issue of pixel rounding...oddly the effect only seems to happen with border widths that are odd numbers.

Comment: Oh BTW, ID's should only be used once per page so `id="box1"` on every box is not correct.

Comment: What does the inspector in your browser show? Given you're zeroing the margin and padding, the only other options are rounding error in your browser or a border. What happens if you zero the border with e.g. `* { border: 0; }`?

Answer (score 1):

```
This seems to be working.
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
  border: 4px black solid;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: red;
  margin:-1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box1" class="grid-item">Box 1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="grid-item">Box 2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="grid-item">Box 3</div>
  <div id="box4" class="grid-item">Box 4</div>
</div>
```